# A 0 byte file is created on desktop

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, file-management

I have a empty folder by the name dev that was somehow created on my Windows7 laptop.It contains a file by the name nul.It has size 0 Bytes and both the folder and the file are hidden and read-only.I would like to know if there is some way by which I can delete the folder and the file.

Comment: How do you know that it has a file called `nul`?  What did you do to determine this?  My educated guess is that if there truly is such a file, it's actually named `null`.  Moreover, what deletion methods have you actually _tried_?

Comment: @JdeBP It is very likely that it is actually called `nul` seeing as how he can't delete it. `nul` is a reserved word in the Windows filesystem and can't normally have files by this name. Trying doing `mkdir nul` and watch what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a freeware called as unlocker to delete undeletable files.

Download Unlocker for Windows [here](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/).

Answer (score 3):

For deleting (and making!) files/folders with Windows reserved names (`con`,`nul`, and a few others), you can use `cmd.exe` and use a UNC longpath like this:

```
del \\?\C:\Full\Path\To\nul
```